# mount encrypted loopback in suse/systemd: unknown filesystem type 'crypt'

Tags: encryption, filesystems, mount, systemd, suse

This might be specific to openSUSE / systemd.

I'm having trouble mounting an encrypted loopback file using the procedure described on the [SDB:Encrypted filesystems](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Encrypted_filesystems#systemd_support) knowledge base. I get this behaviour:

```
[mjl@tesla:~]
[11:12] $ sudo systemctl start /home/mjl/key
Job for home-mjl-key.mount failed. See "systemctl status home-mjl-key.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[mjl@tesla:~]
[11:12] 1 $ sudo systemctl status home-mjl-key.mount
● home-mjl-key.mount - /home/mjl/key
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-03-11 11:12:41 AEDT; 3s ago
    Where: /home/mjl/key
     What: /home/mjl/.tomb
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 12949 ExecMount=/usr/bin/mount /home/mjl/.tomb /home/mjl/key -t crypt -o loop,user,acl,user_xattr (code=exited, status=32)

Mar 11 11:12:41 tesla systemd[1]: Mounting /home/mjl/key...
Mar 11 11:12:41 tesla mount[12949]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypt'
Mar 11 11:12:41 tesla systemd[1]: home-mjl-key.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Mar 11 11:12:41 tesla systemd[1]: Failed to mount /home/mjl/key.
Mar 11 11:12:41 tesla systemd[1]: home-mjl-key.mount: Unit entered failed state.
[mjl@tesla:~]
[11:12] 3 $
```

The /home/mjl/.tomb loopback file was [created using YaST Partitioner](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_security/data/sec_cryptofs_y2.html#sec_cryptofs_y2_container); I specified that I did not want it mounted at system start time, but that users should be allowed to mount it.

So it created the file, added an entry to /etc/cryptab and also this entry to /etc/fstab:

```
[mjl@tesla:~]
[11:12] 3 $ tail -n1 /etc/fstab
/home/mjl/.tomb      /home/mjl/key        crypt      loop,user,noauto,acl,user_xattr,nofail 0 0
[mjl@tesla:~]
[11:15]$
```

There is the 'crypt' filesystem type.

My question is:  how should I be mounting this as a user?  Is systemd failing because of the filesystem type, or because I haven't told it the encryption key?

I've also tried mounting directly:

```
[mjl@tesla:~]
[11:16]$ sudo mount /home/mjl/key
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypt'
[mjl@tesla:~]
```

The same error. So I guess I'm not mounting it correctly. Do I need to do something with cryptsetup

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about) or [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: agreed.  voted to close, asked same in [Super User](https://superuser.com/about) - ([question link](https://superuser.com/questions/1302327/mount-encrypted-loopback-in-suse-systemd-unknown-filesystem-type-crypt))